# Parse Date to compare in JPQL query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date, jpql

I would like to parse an input date in java, and then use it in a query as a condition in a select in oracle database.

```
 String date = "2013.11.05";
    Date checkDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd").parse(date);

    String  qString = 
    "SELECT DISTINCT T " +
    "FROM T5PFArfolyamArch T " +
    "WHERE T.arfTipus = :vcRateKod AND T.arfErvkezd = :checkDate AND T.araValid IN ('I','M')";

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(qString);
query.setParameter("vcRateKod", tipus);
query.setParameter("checkDate", checkDate);
```

But it gives 0 result, like the date is not equal or right format to select anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
query.setParameter("checkDate", checkDate, TemporalType.DATE);
```